# Need string extraction between tags

Tags: bash, command-line

I have a string named as `<tr><td>-Xms36g</td></tr>`

I need to extract Xms36g from it and I have tried and ended successfully with

`grep -oE '[Xms0-9g]' | xargs | sed 's| ||g'`

But I would like to know is there any other way I can achieve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `grep` with PCRE (`-P`)

```
grep -Po -- '-\K[^<]+'
```

- `-` matches `-` literally and `\K` discards the match
- `[^<]+` gets the portion upto next `<` i.e. our desired portion

With `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/^[^-]*-([^<]+)<.*/\1/'
```

- `^[^-]*-` matches substring upto the `-`
- The only captured group, `([^<]+)` gets the portion upto next `<`
- `<.*` matches the rest
- In the replacement we have used the captured group only

**Example:**

```
% grep -Po -- '-\K[^<]+' <<<'<tr><td>-Xms36g</td></tr>'
Xms36g

% sed -E 's/^[^-]*-([^<]+)<.*/\1/' <<<'<tr><td>-Xms36g</td></tr>'
Xms36g
```

Comment: could you please add explanation as well.

Comment: @Raja Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 2):

Parsing HTML with regular expressions is frowned upon. If you have `xmllint` which is shipped with `libxml2-util` you can use this:

```
xmllint --html --xpath '//text()' file
```

You can also pipe to standard input. In this case you need to use `-` for the filename:

```
foo | xmllint --html --xpath '//text()' -
```

Answer (score 1):

There are seemingly endless ways you could do this. Here's an `awk` example:

```
awk -F'-|<' '{print $4}'
```

Another variation:

```
awk -F'[-<]' '$0=$4 {print}'
```

Using `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/.*-([^/<>]*).*/\1/'
```

Using `cut`:

```
cut -b 10-15
```

Using `echo`:

```
echo "${str:9:6}"
```